# If we create multiple Spark Sessions using newSession() method, how is the driver memory shared between multiple spark sessions

Tags: apache-spark

In my Spark Application I am creating multiple (2 - 3) spark sessions with the help of newSession() method. While submitting the applications, I am configuring spark.driver.memory to 24g.

How will this memory get distributed between 2 spark sessions if those are processing 2 different datasets in parallel. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions are used for configuration management not for resource management or parallel in-application processing.  There is no built-in mechanism for any resource allocation, and are part of the same app from the manager perspective.

It means that first-comes-first-gets - there is no separation and however occupies resources first wins.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the usage of Spark Sessions. I was thinking that if I create 2 spark sessions, I could process 2 different datasets at the same time. So that means for my requirement I could as well use same Spark Session to process both the data sets at the same time by submitting spark jobs using java futures. Do you think this would work?